# How to force a MaterialUI Expansion Panel not to be expanded

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Im looking for a way to force the Expansion panel to `expanded=false` when the expansion panel is disabled.
Imagine an expanded Expansion panel. An event occurs and the Expansion Panel switch to disabled.
My problem is that it's still expanded. I want to force `expanded=false` but I don't know how to do.

Here is my code :

```js
return (


<ExpansionPanel disabled={props.body==null} >
  <ExpansionPanelSummary
  expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
  id="panel1a-header"
  classes={{
    content: classes.spaced,
  }}
  >
    <Box fontWeight="fontWeightBold">{props.name}</Box>
    <Box fontWeight="fontWeightBold" className={props.hasError ? classes.error : classes.ok}>
      {props.hasError ? 'DOWN' : 'UP'}
    </Box>
  </ExpansionPanelSummary>
  <ExpansionPanelDetails 
  classes={{
    root: classes.rowSpaced
    }}>
      {
      props.body != null && props.body.checks != null ?

      <Box>
        <List
      component="nav"
      aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
      subheader={
        <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">Liveness</ListSubheader>
      }
      className={classes.root}
      >
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemText>
            <Box display="flex" flexDirection="row" className={classes.spaced}>
              <Typography key={props.body.checks[0].name}>{props.body.checks[0].name}</Typography>
              <Typography key={props.body.checks[0].name + props.body.checks[0].status} className={props.body.checks[0].status === 'UP' ? classes.ok : classes.error}>
                {props.body.checks[0].status}
              </Typography>
            </Box>
          </ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
      </List>

      <Divider />
      <List
      component="nav"
      aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
      subheader={
        <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
          Readyness
        </ListSubheader>
      }
      className={classes.root}
      >
        {
        props.body != null && props.body.checks != null ? props.body.checks.slice(1).sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1).map((check, i) => (

        <ListItem key={check.name + check.status}>
          <ListItemText>
            <Box display="flex" flexDirection="row" className={classes.spaced}>
              <Typography key={check.name}>{check.name}</Typography>
              <Typography key={check.name + check.status}  className={check.status === 'UP' ? classes.ok : classes.error}>
               {check.status}
              </Typography>
            </Box>
          </ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        )) : null
        }
      </List>

      </Box>

      : null
      }


    </ExpansionPanelDetails>
  </ExpansionPanel>
  );
```

If `props.body==null` then the Expansion Panel has to be `disabled=true` AND `expanded=false` because I don't want to keep it expanded when disabled... 
If `this.props.body!=null` then I want to let the user click on it to expand as he wants.

Notice the `props.body != null && props.body.checks != null ?` condition because an async call is made. See [react this.props undefined or empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477518/react-this-props-undefined-or-empty-object)

How to do ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = React.useState(false);
const isDisabled = (props.body === null);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if(isExpanded && isDisabled) {
    setIsExpanded(false);
  }
}, [isExpanded, isDisabled]);
```

```js
<ExpansionPanel disabled={isDisabled} expanded={isExpanded && !isDisabled} onChange={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)}>
....
</ExpansionPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to have the ability to disable/enable the panel, and also the expand/collapse settings - you will need to move to a controlled panel. This means that you need to have a variable that saves the status of the expand/collapse (and probably also the status of the panel (enabled/disabled).

Once the user you have a panel that is disabled - make sure that this change will also set the value of the expand to false:

```
const MyControlledPanel = props => {
  const { children, disabled } = props;
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = () => {
    setIsExpanded(!isExpanded);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (disabled) {
      setIsExpanded(false);
    }
  }, [disabled]);

  return (
    <ExpansionPanel
      disabled={disabled}
      expanded={isExpanded}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      {children}
    </ExpansionPanel>
  );
};
```

> By setting the `isExpanded` to false once you get a `disabled=true` value in the prop - you make sure that even if you get `disabled=false` - the panel is still collapsed (and the user will now be able to expand it again).

You can find here a working version of this:  https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-panel-collapse-on-disable-1ejtt?file=/demo.js

Comment: Well, thank you for the solution. One more thing please. How `isExpanded` can keep the actual value ? Im my app it always swich to `false` when rerendering the compoment. I updated the demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-panel-collapse-on-disable-krnvi?file=/demo.js

Comment: do you have another question? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Yes your answer is correct but in my application i have a strange behaviour. The Expansion Panel always closes itself after some seconds and I don"t understand why

Comment: Any chance you update some content from outside? If so - this might cause re-rendering, and this might reset some of your variables.

Comment: Yes that's it! How to prevent it ?

Comment: This is a bit more general question (and not related at all to material-ui/panel expanding), but you need to make sure that the props change will not affect the child component (you can store the data in a const (useState) and use this const to pass data to the child-component, and this way changes in the parent will not change anything in the child. There are also other ways to solve this, but first you need to understand the root cause.